# Optimising the Magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2, backend, optimization, speedoptimization

In general, the loading times of pages in the backend are around 2 seconds. Can't really argue with that. However, I have noticed that Grid Pages (such as the Order and Products) require additional time to finish rendering the page.

If you look at Chrome you can see that after the page loads, it takes ad additional 2 seconds to render the Grid with the Order/Product Data.

[image]

Having looked at the loading assets, the following asset is to culprit. It appears that this is responsible for retrieving data from the database. The waterfall data attributes the time down to the TTFB.

[image]

What I find interesting, is that if you use any of the Filters or Searches after the page loads, the page renders with the results almost instantly. It's just that initial page load.

However, the reason for this post is an attempt to shed some more light on the following:

- As I have no other Production environments to benchmark against, is the Load vs Finish time a reasonable expectation? i.e. Should I even bother to attempt to optimise this
- If I were to optimise this, should I be looking at PHP or MySQL as root of the TTFB delay?

Side Note: It also appears that limiting both the **Number of Results** and the **Number of Columns** has a small but positive effect on Finish time.

Comment: IMHO 6 second load time in admin is okay. You will struggle to optimise more.

Comment: Trying to keep sales staff happy. It's a long time to wait when you have a customer on the phone.

Comment: Do you have any optimisation in place to make the frontend faster already?

Comment: you have absolutely perfect loading time, don't bother

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box in order to keep sales staff happy what if you had something custom outside of magento to build the quote and then use the magento API to generate and finalise the order? At POS it would be fast.

Beyond that if you want to keep it in magento you are going to be fighting the framework to get much more of an improvement.